# Unreadable text - dialog with goofy robot icon in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, coldfusion, vscode-extensions

I'm using Microsoft VS Code 1.87.2 to edit a website written with ColdFusion.  I've updated the background color of the VS Code IDE to money green (RGB 192,220,192) and overall this is working well.

While editing a .cfm (ColfFusion) software file from a git repository, I see almost unreadable dim gray text about source control added to the on-screen text.  When I click on the very dim gray text, this dialog appears with a goofy robot with sunglasses.

Two of the programming extensions to VS Code are GitLens and Adobe ColdFusion Builder.

Can anybody help me with what component is adding the very dim gray text to my screen?  I'm hoping the dim gray text is from the same provider as the goofy robot dialog attached, and that I will be able to update a setting to make the text more visible for my programming.

This could be VS Code, GitLens or Adobe ColdFusion Builder extensions... or even "some other" extension?

I tried Google Lens but it did not find the goofy robot icon.

[image]

Comment: It appears to be GitLens displaying the unreadable text.  This narrows my question down to a "how to" on updating GitLens theming.  Before posting I had reviewed the GitLens UI settings and not found or recognized such a setting.

Comment: It does seem gitlens related, and I don't see any color settings for it unfortunately.

Comment: I had this issue, recently, with a purple theme. https://twitter.com/Bardnet/status/1757535980402118677. Still, no solution

Comment: with the Developer tools inspect if that text uses some theme color